# CSS content div fills screen width with floating sidebar

Tags: html, css

I have a 2 column layout set where the left column is the main content holder, and the right column functions as a sidebar. I want the sidebar to be a fixed size in pixels, and the main content to adjust depending on window size: https://jsfiddle.net/n0y408m2/

```css
#itemList {
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

#sidePanel {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#buttonContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#buttonContainer button {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

#infoContainer {
  background-color: #d3e2eb;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="sidePanel">
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Add Item</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" disabled>Delete Item</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" disabled>Edit Item</button>
  </div>
  <div id="infoContainer">
    <h4 class="text-center">Information</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="itemList">
  <h3>Main content</h3>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

I want to make it so that if the main content gets too long, scroll bars will show, and the sidebar will become fixed and scroll with the page so it always stays in the same location

I can achieve this by setting `position:fixed; right:0` on the sidebar. But now the main content fills 100% of the screen width when it should still be flush with the left edge of the side bar

I guess the layout now no longer knows about the fixed px width of the sidebar. Whats the best way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already added float right to your side-panel, giving `margin-right` will fix your problem.

This will work for you [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/n0y408m2/2/)

```
    #itemList {
      margin-top: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: green;
      margin-right: 315px;
    }

    #sidePanel {
      background-color: red;
      float: right;
      width: 300px;
      padding-left: 10px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      position: fixed;
      right: 0;
    }

    #buttonContainer {
      width: 100%;
      padding-top: 20px;
    }

    #buttonContainer button {
      display: block;
      width: 70%;
      margin: 0 auto 20px;
    }

    #infoContainer {
      background-color: #d3e2eb;
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }


  [1]: https://jsfid
```

Answer (score 0):

i made a `@media query` so under `767px` side-bar becomes fixed.
also added a `margin-right:300px` to the main content, which is the width of the side-bar

also add `box-sizing:border-box` to `#sidePanel` so it has a 300px width not 320 ( because of the padding left and right of 10px )

see snippet below or fiddle > [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0y408m2/1/)

```css
#itemList {
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: green;
}

#sidePanel {
  background-color: red;
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

#buttonContainer {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#buttonContainer button {
  display: block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
}

#infoContainer {
  background-color: #d3e2eb;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #sidePanel { position:fixed;right:0}
  #itemList {margin-right:300px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="sidePanel">
  <div id="buttonContainer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-md">Add Item</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" disabled>Delete Item</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" disabled>Edit Item</button>
  </div>

  <div id="infoContainer">
    <h4 class="text-center">Information</h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="itemList">
  <h3>Main content</h3>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why we require `media-queries` here? If he doesn't want to have different behavior for small screen.

Comment: he said : `I want to make it so that if the main content gets too long, scroll bars will show, and the sidebar will become fixed` . the content can get too long if the screen gets smaller. isn't that right ? that's why i made an example media query

Answer (score 0):

you have to set width for both divs other wise the div whose width doesn't fix will occupy 100% width
Add following properties in your stylesheet

```
#itemList {
    width: calc(100% - 310px);
}
#sidePanel {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can get it done by adding:

```
 height: 100vh;
```

to the `#itemList` and

```
layout: fixed;
```

to the `#sidePanel:`

```
#sidePanel {
     background-color: red;
     float: right;
     width: 300px;
     padding-left: 10px;
     padding-right: 10px;
     layout: fixed;
}

#itemList {
   margin-top: 10px;
   overflow: auto;
   background-color: green;
   height: 100vh;
}
```

Hope it helps.